Why numpy data type kind returns void when it was created as float64?
I have this code:
>>> d = np.dtype([("pos", np.float64, 3)])
>>> d[0].kind
'V'

Why does it return 'V' instead of 'f'? In the full code, I need to know if the field corresponds to an integer, float, string...

d[0].kind does not return 'f' because it is not a floating-point dtype: it is a structured dtype with a floating point base.
There are several other attributes of structured dtypes that you might be able to inspect depending on your particular goal. For example:
>>> d[0].base
dtype('float64')
>>> d[0].subdtype[0].kind
'f'


Your answer explains clearly the issue (that's why I select it), however it's not applicable for all posible cases in my code, where I have things like atom = np.dtype([("specie", str), ("pos", np.float64, 3)]). The field specie has no subdtype. As you said, 'depending on your particular goal'. In all possible cases for my code, d[0].base.kind works.

You need to get the base:
import numpy as np

d = np.dtype([("pos", np.float64, 3)])

print(d[0].base.kind)


Because the numpy.dtype.kind only gives you the type character of the array's scalar type and this is due to the fact that structured data types are of void data type, instead of being as the specific type of their individual elements.

I didn't realize that field is a structured data type (it's something I'm learning today).

Not sure why you get V (this seems due to the shape since np.dtype([("pos", np.float64)])[0].kind returns 'f'), but you could access the base type:
d = np.dtype([("pos", np.float64, 3)])

d[0].base.kind
# 'f'


Looking at your more complicated dtype
In [20]: atom = np.dtype([("specie", str), ("pos", np.float64, 3)])

In [21]: atom
Out[21]: dtype([('specie', '<U'), ('pos', '<f8', (3,))])

In [22]: atom.fields
Out[22]: mappingproxy({'specie': (dtype('<U'), 0), 'pos': (dtype(('<f8', (3,))), 0)})

You have two fields, one with a shape, the other just 'plain':
In [23]: atom['pos']
Out[23]: dtype(('<f8', (3,)))

In [24]: atom['pos'].base
Out[24]: dtype('float64')

In [25]: atom['specie']
Out[25]: dtype('<U')

In [26]: atom['specie'].base
Out[26]: dtype('<U')

The field of a composite dtype is also a dtype, and has the same collection of attributes as listed on https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html
To fully understand a dtype, I still need to pick it apart and look at the pieces.
